# How to trigger empty value validation in Django functional test?

Tags: python, django, tdd

I am new to Django and I am now reading the "Test-Driven Development with Python' book for learning.
However, when I want to test the empty-value validation, the unit test is ok, but the functional test is failed.

I am now using Django 2.1, Python 3. I have tried my best to check the reason of the problem but still failed to pass the functional test

models.py

```
...
class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(default='')
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py

```
...
def new_list(request):
    list_ = List.objects.create()
    item = Item.objects.create(text=request.POST['item_text'],list=list_)
    try:
        item.full_clean()
        item.save()
    except ValidationError:
        list_.delete()
        error = "You can't have an empty list item"
        return render(request, 'home.html', {"error": error})

    return redirect(list_)
```

test_views.py (Unit Test-Successful)

```
...
def test_validation_errors_are_sent_back_to_home_page_template(self):
    response = self.client.post('/lists/new', data={'item_text':''})
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'home.html')
    expected_error = escape("You can't have an empty list item")
    self.assertContains(response, expected_error)
```

test_list_item_validation.py (Functional Test-Failed)

```
...
def test_cannot_add_empty_list_items(self):
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
    self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_new_item').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    error = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.has-error')
    self.assertEqual(error.text, "You can't have an empty list item")
```

base.html (All html files extend from this)

```
...
{% if error %}
    <div class="form-group has-error">
        <span class="help-block">{{ error }}</span>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

I expect that both the unit test and functional test are correct, but the actual result is the unit test is passed but the functional test is failed

Answer (score 1):

Great book. Read it myself. I believe this is the part that you are missing:

```
def test_cannot_add_empty_list_items(self):
    # Edith goes to the home page and accidentally tries to submit
    # an empty list item. She hits Enter on the empty input box
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
    self.get_item_input_box().send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    '''
    If you keep reading a little farther, it should tell you that modern browsers
    will not submit forms when fields that are 'required' left are blank.
    '''
    # The browser intercepts the request, and does not load the
    # list page
    self.wait_for(lambda: self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        '#id_text:invalid'  
    ))
```

If you keep reading a little farther, it should tell you that 'modern browsers will not submit `forms` when fields that are `required` are left blank. It should give you the code amendment above.